# Random rotations in SO(3) and free group

Tags: pr.probability

Is it true that two random (w.r.t. Haar measure) rotations in $SO(3)$ generate a free group?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes.  Here's what should be a proof: the set of pairs of elements satisfying any particular relation is Zariski closed, hence has measure zero (to show that it is not $SO(3) \times SO(3)$ it suffices to know that at least one subgroup generated by two elements is free), and there are countably many relations.

Comment: Right, the only non-trivial part of showing that there exists at least one pair of rotations, which generate a free group, was proved first by Felix Hausdorff.

Comment: Two such elements are given in this blog post: http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/09/17/that-trick-where-you-embed-the-free-group-into-a-lie-group/

Comment: @Andreas a conceptual (though not terribly elementary) way to see that $SO(3)$ contains a free group is by the following argument. First note that it is enough to show that $SU(2)$ contains one. To see that $SU(2)$ has one, by a Baire category argument, it is enough to see that for each word in $F_2$ there is a pair in $SU(2)$ which does not satisfy it. As this is an algebraic question, it is enough to show it for the complexification, $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. But this is obvious, as it contains $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, which contains a free group...

Answer (score 6):

See also:  [Epstein - Almost all subgroups of a Lie group are free](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869371901074) ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=281776)).