# Unitary and injective representation of a free group 

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Is there an example of an **injective** homomorphism
$\pi: F_2\to U(n)$ of the 2 generator free group $F_2$
in some unitary group of matrices $U(n)$?

Comment: Yes, of course. This is one of the main points of Banach-Tarski. Explicit constructions can be found here, for example: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49363/cheap-non-constructive-free-group-generating-rotations-for-banach-tarski

Comment: Dear Theo, did i missed something or the examples in these explicit constructions the generators are invertible, but not unitary matrices? many thanks

Comment: @Paulo: the constructions there include an injective homomorphism into $\text{SO}(3)$, which is compact Lie, so embeds in a unitary group (in this case we can take $\text{U}(3)$).  

Comment: Dear Qiaochu, you are right! many thanks

Comment: Using the fact that the universal cover of $SO(3)$ is $SU(2)$, together with the fact that every homomorphism of the free group can be lifted (a consequence of freeness), you can construct explicit homomorphisms of $F_2$ into $SU(2)$.

Comment: Of course one could invoke the Tits alternative, stating that in characteristic 0 any not virtually solvable subgroup of $GL_n$ contains $F_2$... but that would be a bit pedantic!