# Can two rational rotations $F_2 = \langle A, B \rangle \to SO(3)$ efficiently approximate the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems, diophantine-approximation

Let $A,B$ be two rational rotations:

$$ A = \left[\begin{array}{rcc} \frac{3}{5} & \frac{4}{5} & 0 \\
-\frac{4}{5} & \frac{3}{5} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right] 
\quad\text{ and }\quad
B = \left[\begin{array}{crc} 
1 & 0 & 0  \\ 
0 & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{4}{5}  \\
0 & -\frac{4}{5} & \frac{3}{5}   \end{array}\right]
$$

Then we build the free group $\mathbb{F}_2 = \langle A, B \rangle$ of all possible products of $A, B, A^{-1}, B^{-1}$.  Or I think since we chose $A,B$ to be rotations, we have a **homomorphism**

$$ \phi:  \mathbb{F}_2 \to SO(3)$$

just by evaluating the product.  The image $\langle A,B \rangle$ is obviously dense in $SO(3)$, but how much work is it to find products of $A$ and $B$ that are very close to the identity as a function of the word length $n$?

$SO(3)$ only has [a few](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ginsparg/physics/phys446-546/disc3d.pdf) discrete subgroups.  Proving that $\overline{\langle A,B \rangle} = SO(3)$ seems to be a matter of the pigeonhole principle or maybe showing this group is dense [Zariski topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Zariski+site).

Kaloshin and Rodnianski suggest this is always the case for pretty much any collecton of rotations in [Diophantine Properties of $SO(3)$](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~kaloshin/research/dioph-SO3.pdf).  I am wondering if the argument simplifies for any specific choice of group elements.

On my computer this morning I was able to find:

$$ AB^{-1}A^{-3}B^{-1}A^2 =
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
 0.98189568 & -0.12261376 &  0.144384  \\
        0.15538176 &  0.95731968 & -0.243712  \\
       -0.10833920 &  0.26173440 &  0.959040    \end{array}\right]$$

which is not that close to the identity matrix, but it's the best one I can find with 8 letters.

Maybe there's a "cheap trick"  that works here.  I would especially love that.  This seemed like such an easy problem, but all the solutions I found are quite hard.

Comment: proving density $\langle A,B \rangle = SO(3)$ seems [hard](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47585/random-rotations-in-so3-and-free-group)

Comment: also... despite [floating point error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) using decimals seems correct since if I just use rationals, I am saying implicitly $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but what's the problem with the implicit statement that $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: 1) I'm puzzled by the fact you say that the density of the subgroup $\langle A,B\rangle$ is obvious in your message, and that is seems hard in your comment. It's not trivial but it's not hard (each generates a dense subgroup of two "orthogonal" copies of $SO(3)$ and it's easy to conclude.

Comment: 2) "find product of $A,B$ that are very close to identity is vague: possibly you mean an element of the subgroup generated by $A$ and $B$ (then you should require a non-trivial element of the free group, or a nontrivial element, which is the same is $(A,B)$ is a free family. Or you mean, in the semigroup generated by $A$ and $B$, and the latter is also dense (by the same argument, since the positive powers of $A$ are dense in the corresponding copy of $SO(2)$, etc, so this is a reasonable question too.

Comment: @ycor no link and i could not find the review of Sevennec

Comment: 3) Related: here's a survey (in French) by Sevennec about equirepartition of subgroups in $SO(3)$: http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/sevennec/txt-lebesgue.ps

Comment: There seems to be relation to Banach-Tarski paradox. I found in his note the explicit case of rotation by $\cos^-1(3/5)$. No calculations but he mentions Arnold, Rodnianski and others.

Comment: Proving density isn't hard. The closure $\overline{\langle A,B \rangle}$ is a closed subgroup of $SO(3)$, and the complete listing of those is known; it is not too hard to rule out all options other than $SO(3)$ itself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Setting $a_0=A^7, b_0=B^7$ and then $a_{n+1}=[b_n^{-1},a_n], b_{n+1}=[a_n,b_n]$ seems very efficient. The length grows like $C \alpha^n$ with $\alpha= \frac{3 + \sqrt{17}}2$ and the operator norm distance to the identity matrix gets squared in each step, since
$$\|1 - [a,b]\| \leq 2 \|1-a\| \cdot \|1-b\|.$$ I used a similar construction in [On the length of the shortest non-trivial element in the derived and the lower central series](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0138). I do not think this is best possible, but it is very explicit.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried b^{-34}*a^{34}

It gets pretty close...
  $b^{-34}*a^{34} = \left[ \begin{matrix} 0.9937  & 0.1119  &  0  \\ -0.1112 & 0.9875 & -0.1119 \\ -0.0125 & 0.1112 & 0.9937 \end{matrix} \right]$

in fact chaining b^-17*a^17*...*b^-17*a^17 an even number of times will get you closer while maintaining unit determinant...

$b^{-17}a^{17}b^{-17}a^{17}b^{-17}a^{17}b^{-17}a^{17}=$
$\left[ \begin{matrix} 1.0000  &  0.0002  & -0.0063  \\ -0.0002 &   1.0000   &-0.0002 \\    0.0063 &   0.0002   & 1.0000 \end{matrix} \right]$

Are these results product of rounding errors?

No!

The geometric meaning is that $17 \cdot \arccos(3/5) \approx 5\pi$, so $a^{17}$ is like rotating two and a half times around the $\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right]$ axis, and $a^{34}$ is 5 way round, so you obtain the identity (approximately).

You could chase down the decimals after $\arccos(3/5)$ and get so close to identity as you wish. And the same goes with b. The question about combinations of powers of multiples other than 17 is far more difficult.